# Backing Up Apps With allowBackup=false

Tags: adb, backup, apk

I'm trying to back up the apks and preference data for all of the apps on my device, but it only backs up about a third of them; the remainder all have `allowBackup=false` in their manifests, which disables the ability to back them up, either with `adb` or with Helium.

I'd much prefer *not* to have to go through each of the apks one by one, extract their manifests, change them, then make them apks and add them to my device again. So is there a way of ignoring `allowBackup=false` when doing `adb backup`? Or, is there an app or shell command I could run that would find all of the apps with `allowBackup` set to `false` and set them to `true`?

I checked out [this app that's supposed to do just that](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.backupallapps), but was unable to run it since it doesn't have an activity specified. If there's any easy way of getting that to work, or any alternative to it, that would be great.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Do you have Xposed installed? Then there's a module (BackupAllApps, if I remember the name correctly) which could help you out that simply allows all backups via ADB (ignoring the `allowBackup` setting).

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately my device _isn't_ rooted. I'm not sure, but as best I understand it, I'd have to unlock the bootloader to root it, effectively wiping the device and nulling the point of backing it up.

Comment: Without root powers, there is no way, sorry.

Comment: @laef Depending on your Android version you may be vulnerable against a root exploit which can allow you to get a root shell just by executing the exploit - no reboot, no wipe. Common "suspects" are e.g. towelroot. Check your security patch level date to see if your device OS is old enough.

Answer (score -5):

allowBackup=false
This is specifically put into the application by the developer so that people can not make a copy of the application ( usually to stop reverse engineering )

It would probably constitute as copyright if you ignored the allowBackup=false and made a copy of it anyway, so most applications won't allow it to respect other developers wishes.

This obviously would apply to rooted phones as well.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really answer my question. I know _why_ many apps set `allowBackup` to `false`. However, considering that the data each app keeps was generated by my use of the app, I think it's fair to consider that I have a right to back up such data.

Comment: The user generated content would be stored inside data, So instead of opening system folder, you'd open the data folder ... Usually it's DATA > DATA > PACKAGE.NAME > USER GENERATED FOLDERS > USER GENERATED FILES .... So the path will look like data/data/my.app.name/assets/file.txt

Comment: For the sake of the argument, you could research whether making copies for backup purposes effectively constitutes copyright infringement, or if it's mere speculation, no?